# On a reply get ID and or content of the original message

Tags: python, telethon

I am making a script to analyse a telegram channel.

I would like to get the event.id or event.text of the original message when the channel is replying on a previous message.

Of course I looked in into the documentation but I am not able to figure it out.

[Clarification of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNSnX.png)

My code:

```
@telegram_client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=testchannel))
def new_message_testchannel(event):
    message_raw_text = event.raw_text
    if event.is_reply:
        print('Reply')
        # Get original message ID and or content
        message_raw_text_reply = event.get_message_reply()
        # or
        message_raw_text_reply = event.get_message_reply().raw_text
        # or
        message_raw_text_reply = event.get_message_reply().id
        print(message_raw_text_reply)
    else:
        print('Normal message: ', message_raw_text)


telegram_client.start()
telegram_client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: What exact issue are you encountering? What is your expected output?

Comment: So let's say I send a message [Original message] and after that I reply on that message. I want to know what the message (preferable id) of that reply was. In this case [Original message]

Answer (score 1):

It had indeed something to do with the async
here is my code example that is working :-)

```
@telegram_client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=testchannel))
async def new_message_testchannel(event):
    message_raw_text = event.raw_text
    if event.is_reply:
        print(event.id)
        reply = await event.get_reply_message()
        reply_raw_text = reply.raw_text
        reply_id = reply.id
        print('Is reply')
        print(reply_raw_text, reply_id)
        print(type(reply))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is partially correct but is missing the asyncio part.
Telethon is an async library so all network calls need to be awaited.

```
@telegram_client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=testchannel))
async def new_message_testchannel(event):
    message_raw_text = event.raw_text
    if event.is_reply:
        print('Reply')
        # Get original message ID and or content
        message_reply = await event.get_message_reply()
        # or
        message_raw_text_reply = message_reply.raw_text
        # or
        message_id_reply = message_reply.id
        print(message_raw_text_reply)
        print(message_id_reply )
    else:
        print('Normal message: ', message_raw_text)


telegram_client.start()
telegram_client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: I have tested your code but it didn't work either, it just prints 'Reply' but no original message nor id